# Blazor ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator issue

Tags: validation, blazor

I am using `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` and `ValidateComplexType` to validate form.
After the focus out from `InputText`, the validation reports an error regardless of whether the field is filled in correctly.
[invalid form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Xmh.png)

When I validate form with `EditContext.Validate()`, validation works as expected.
[valid form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SXuM.png)

`InputText` binds `Name` property from dto object:
(For testing purposes, I have set the identifiers to the classes.)

```cs
public class TestDto
{
    private string _name;
    public string InstanceId { get; private set; }
    public string ViewModelInstanceId { get; private set; }

    Required(ErrorMessage = "Name fieild is required.")]
    public string Name 
    {   
    // after focus out event on InputText, first call of this getter is from old empty (new) instance created on OnInitialized
    // ViewModelInstanceId is always the same, as expected
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }

    public TestDto(string viewModelInstanceId)
    {
        ViewModelInstanceId = viewModelInstanceId;
        InstanceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

My razor page

```razor
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <p>
        <InputText @bind-Value="ViewModel.TestDto.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="()=>ViewModel.TestDto.Name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button @onclick="()=>ViewModel.ValidateForm?.Invoke()">Validate form</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>

@code{
    protected EditContext EditContext { get; set; } = null!;

    [ValidateComplexType]
    protected TestViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ViewModel = new TestViewModel();
        
        //If this line is removed, everything works as expected
        ViewModel.TestDto = new TestDto(ViewModel.InstanceIdId) //Instance1
        {
            Name = string.Empty//this makes validation to fail because it is required field
        };
        ViewModel.ValidateForm = () => EditContext.Validate();
        
        EditContext = new EditContext(ViewModel);//Validates form as expected
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(firstRender){
            ViewModel.LoadTestDto();//Instance2
            StateHasChanged();
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

View model

```cs
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string InstanceId { get; private set; }
    public string PageTitle => "Test page";
    public Func<bool> ValidateForm { get; set; }

    [ValidateComplexType]
    public TestDto TestDto { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
        => InstanceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public void LoadTestDto()
    {
        TestDto = new TestDto(InstanceId)//Instance2
        {
            Name = "Loaded name"
        };
    }
}
```

So, I have decide to test `TestDto.Name` getter and setter.
After focus out from `InputText`, those were hitted breakpoints on `Name` getter and setter:

1. `Name` setter => setted new entered value to `Instance2` (created on `OnAfterRender`)
2. `Name` getter => returns empty value from `Instance1` ?!? (created on `OnInitialized`)
3. `Name` getter => returns new entered value from `Instance2` (created on `OnAfterRender`)
4. ...

Any ideas? I am brainwashed :D and probably overlooked something :/

P.S. In case when `TestDto` instance is setted only during `OnAfterRendering` event, everything works as expected, but that isn't desired scenario.

**EDIT:**

Why am I creating empty instance of `TestDto` on `OnInitialized`?
Because I can not set `@bind-Value` of nullable object.
Something like this:

```razor
<InputText @bind-Value="ViewModel?.TestDto?.Name" />
```

I know I can hide form like:

```razor
@if(ViewModel.TestDto != null)
{
  <InputText @bind-Value="ViewModel.TestDto.Name" />
}
```

but I want to show empty form before data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning `EditContext` after new `TestDto` instance is set to `TestViewModel.TestDto` property fixes all..

So, on `TestViewModel.TestDto` setter I had to invoke method from razor base class to reassign `EditContext` property

TestViewModel

```cs
[ValidateComplexType]
public TestDto TestDto
{
  get => _testDto;
  set
  {
     testDto= value;
     ReassignEditContext?.Invoke();
  }
}
```

Razor.cs

```cs
private void ReassignEditContext()
   => EditContext = new EditContext(TestViewModel);
```

I just can't believe that is right way to do it...
Does anyone have better idea?

Similar test project can be found on https://github.com/CashPJ/EditFormValidationTest